# Running shell script as root using apache/php

Tags: php, shell, permissions, root

I want to change the permissions of directories using a shell script which gets executed by a [php](/questions/tagged/php), so this runs under the `apache` user.
Unfortunately there are some directories whose permissions are set to `root`.

Is there way to run this script as `root` or are there other alternatives I can consider?

Answer (score 0):

You look for tool called `sudo`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo But most likely instead of going for sudo you should rethink your app architecture as once your httpd is compromised, attacker can easily get root rights.

Comment: Hmm, I decided to use cgi script suid. Thanx for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
    $shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
    $return1  = $shell->exeCmd("/path/to/script");
    //the return will be a string containing the return of the script
    echo $return1;
```

or you could simply bypass the script and just issue the raw commands through the shell directly in PHP. That approach would allow you to handle exceptions.